# How to Ingest data in to Azure Cluster using Python

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, azure-data-explorer, azure-cloud-services

I have a set of data that I would like to query using the KQL using Azure Data Explorer. I have a continuous source of incoming data every few seconds. This data I would like to put into the Azure Cluster to run a query.

I have explored few options using python library but it only supports using file or blob.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/python-ingest-data

How do I put single record using python into so that I can query using Azure Data Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's sample code for ingesting from a data frame (with one or more records) using the `azure-kusto-ingest` library [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/97a5ebed797b8190cd4e94dd347a9f69af524150/azure-kusto-ingest/tests/sample.py#L106)

```py
cluster = "https://ingest-{cluster_name}.kusto.windows.net/"

# In case you want to authenticate with AAD application.
client_id = "<insert here your AAD application id>"
client_secret = "<insert here your AAD application key>"

# read more at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/find-your-office-365-tenant-id
authority_id = "<insert here your tenant id>"

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(cluster, client_id, client_secret, authority_id)

client = QueuedIngestClient(kcsb)

# there are a lot of useful properties, make sure to go over docs and check them out
ingestion_props = IngestionProperties(
    database="{database_name}",
    table="{table_name}",
    data_format=DataFormat.CSV,
    # in case status update for success are also required (remember to import ReportLevel from azure.kusto.ingest)
    # report_level=ReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses,
    # in case a mapping is required (remember to import IngestionMappingKind from azure.kusto.data.data_format)
    # ingestion_mapping_reference="{json_mapping_that_already_exists_on_table}",
    # ingestion_mapping_kind= IngestionMappingKind.JSON,
)

###########################
## ingest from dataframe ##
###########################

import pandas

fields = ["id", "name", "value"]
rows = [[1, "abc", 15.3], [2, "cde", 99.9]]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=fields)

client.ingest_from_dataframe(df, ingestion_properties=ingestion_props)
```

Comment: It worked. Thx. but have doubt more.  Let's say I have 5 columns in table and below given last three columns but still it ingests data into first column. It is not checking the field names and blindly puts the data.

fields = ["id", "name", "value"]
rows = [[1, "abc", 15.3], [2, "cde", 99.9]]

Comment: you may want to clarify your question. i have found it to be unclear. either way, the schema of the dataframe you ingest should match the schema of the table you're ingesting into (in terms of datatypes and order. column names are irrelevant, unless you're using an ingestion mapping)